# How to add target={_blank} to all editor links by default?

Tags: reactjs, lexicaljs, lexical-editor

I want all my editor links to open in a new tab with `target={blank}`

From documentation I did not find a way to do it!

Ι have add the `LinkEditor` implementation, but I don't understand from [documentation-api](https://lexical.dev/docs/api/) where to add `setTarget` attribute to `LinkNode`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found it, and it is what I want!
I leave it here for anyone else with the same worry.

I replaced `editor.dispatchCommand(TOGGLE_LINK_COMMAND, linkUrl)`
with
`editor.dispatchCommand(TOGGLE_LINK_COMMAND, { url: linkUrl, target: '_blank' })` at the point which I set the link to editor!

Comment: Where did you go about setting this?

I thought by reading the documentation, we would be able to achieve this by providing the optional `attributes` to one of the matchers for the `AutoLinkPlugin`. I tried following the [docs](https://lexical.dev/docs/react/plugins#lexicalautolinkplugin) here.

Comment: `AutoLinkPlugin` is something else, as docs mentioned: 
Plugin will convert text into links based on passed matchers list. In example below whenever user types url-like string it will automaticaly convert it into a link node.
What we want is the link to have by default `target: '_blank'`

Comment: So I created an `LinkEditor` component and `onKeyDown` I have add this func

`const onKeyboard = (event: any) => {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      event.preventDefault();
      if (lastSelection !== null) {
        if (linkUrl !== '') {
          editor.dispatchCommand(TOGGLE_LINK_COMMAND, { url: linkUrl, target: '_blank' });
        }
        setEditMode(false);
      }
    } else if (event.key === 'Escape') {
      event.preventDefault();
      setEditMode(false);
    }
  };`